# HTML Truncating in Python

Tags: python, html, truncation

Is there a pure-Python tool to take some HTML and truncate it as close to a given length as possible, but make sure the resulting snippet is well-formed?  For example, given this HTML:

```
<h1>This is a header</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

it would not produce:

```
<h1>This is a hea
```

but:

```
<h1>This is a header</h1>
```

or at least:

```
<h1>This is a hea</h1>
```

I can't find one that works, though I found one that relies on `pullparser`, which is both obsolete and dead.

Comment: "it would produce:" .. given what parameters? number of chars in a row? number of dom-elements, hierarchy?

Comment: Probably either a number of content characters or a number of HTML characters.  I'm not picky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you need a full-fledged parser - you only need to tokenize the the input string into one of:

- text
- open tag
- close tag
- self-closing tag
- character entity

Once you have a stream of tokens like that, it's easy to use a stack to keep track of what tags need closing.  I actually ran into this problem a while ago and wrote a small library to do this:

https://github.com/eentzel/htmltruncate.py

It's worked well for me, and handles most of the corner cases well, including arbitrarily nested markup, counting character entities as a single character, returning an error on malformed markup, etc.

It will produce:

```
<h1>This is a hea</h1>
```

on your example. This could perhaps be changed, but it's hard in the general case - what if you're trying to truncate to 10 characters, but the `<h1>` tag isn't closed for another, say, 300 characters?

Comment: This is exactly what I worked out, and wrote myself.  The only practical difference between yours and mine was that I made it possible to truncate only at inter-word locations.

Comment: I needed exactly that and made implemented inter-word breaks. It's very simple, the diff towards the original is like 5 lines -- https://github.com/enkore/typeflow/blob/master/htmltruncate.py around line fifty

Answer (score 7):

If you're using DJANGO lib, you can simply :

```
from django.utils import text, html

    class class_name():


        def trim_string(self, stringf, limit, offset = 0):
            return stringf[offset:limit]

        def trim_html_words(self, html, limit, offset = 0):
            return text.truncate_html_words(html, limit)


        def remove_html(self, htmls, tag, limit = 'all', offset = 0):
            return html.strip_tags(htmls)
```

Anyways, here's the code from truncate_html_words from django :

```
import re

def truncate_html_words(s, num):
    """
    Truncates html to a certain number of words (not counting tags and comments).
    Closes opened tags if they were correctly closed in the given html.
    """
    length = int(num)
    if length <= 0:
        return ''
    html4_singlets = ('br', 'col', 'link', 'base', 'img', 'param', 'area', 'hr', 'input')
    # Set up regular expressions
    re_words = re.compile(r'&.*?;|<.*?>|([A-Za-z0-9][\w-]*)')
    re_tag = re.compile(r'<(/)?([^ ]+?)(?: (/)| .*?)?>')
    # Count non-HTML words and keep note of open tags
    pos = 0
    ellipsis_pos = 0
    words = 0
    open_tags = []
    while words <= length:
        m = re_words.search(s, pos)
        if not m:
            # Checked through whole string
            break
        pos = m.end(0)
        if m.group(1):
            # It's an actual non-HTML word
            words += 1
            if words == length:
                ellipsis_pos = pos
            continue
        # Check for tag
        tag = re_tag.match(m.group(0))
        if not tag or ellipsis_pos:
            # Don't worry about non tags or tags after our truncate point
            continue
        closing_tag, tagname, self_closing = tag.groups()
        tagname = tagname.lower()  # Element names are always case-insensitive
        if self_closing or tagname in html4_singlets:
            pass
        elif closing_tag:
            # Check for match in open tags list
            try:
                i = open_tags.index(tagname)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                # SGML: An end tag closes, back to the matching start tag, all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags
                open_tags = open_tags[i+1:]
        else:
            # Add it to the start of the open tags list
            open_tags.insert(0, tagname)
    if words <= length:
        # Don't try to close tags if we don't need to truncate
        return s
    out = s[:ellipsis_pos] + ' ...'
    # Close any tags still open
    for tag in open_tags:
        out += '</%s>' % tag
    # Return string
    return out
```

Comment: I'm using CherryPy, but it might be worth importing `django.utils.text` if it's not too much added startup cost.  I'll try it.

Comment: The `truncate_html_words` function is in http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/text.py.

Comment: Parsing HTML using Regular Expressions (like Django does above) is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @slacy: It's not parsing HTML, it's counting the number of open tags. That's a much simpler problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer by slacy very helpful and would upvote it if I had the reputation,  - however there was one extra thing to note. In my environment I had html5lib installed as well as BeautifulSoup4. BeautifulSoup used the html5lib parser and this resulted in my html snippet being wrapped in html and body tags which is not what I wanted.

```
>>> truncate_html("<p>sdfsdaf</p>", 4)
u'<html><head></head><body><p>s</p></body></html>'
```

To resolve these issues I told BeautifulSoup to use the python parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def truncate_html(html, length): 
    return unicode(BeautifulSoup(html[:length], "html.parser"))

>>> truncate_html("<p>sdfsdaf</p>", 4)
u'<p>s</p>'
```

Comment: Just want to let readers know: Awesome answer and very robust. Works for `
truncate_html("<h1><p>123456789</", 9)` returning `<h1><p>12</p></h1>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one line with BeautifulSoup (assuming you want to truncate at a certain number of source characters, not at a number of content characters):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def truncate_html(html, length): 
    return unicode(BeautifulSoup(html[:length]))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will serve your requirement.An easy to use HTML parser and bad markup corrector

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: I looked here first before asking the question.  It's not bad, but it's up to me to count content characters and truncate at the right point, though it does a nice job of fixing the markup once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought would be use an XML parser (maybe [python's sax parser](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html)), then probably count the text characters in each xml element. I would ignore the tags characters count to make it more consistent as well as simpler, but either should be possible.

Comment: As I commented on funktku's answer, hasn't *someone* already done that?

Comment: @JasonFruit Oh I see what you mean now - I don't know if its really that common frankly and its simple enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first completely parsing the HTML then truncate. A great HTML parser for python is [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). After parsing and truncating, you can print it back in to HTML format.

Comment: But hasn't *someone* already done that?  I understand the problem, but it seems like such a common one that someone must have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to cleanup/reformat/reindent HTML.

Comment: Not the best option, and not really a Python thing.

Comment: There is a couple Python libraries binding to Tidy, check it out. I use it to cleanup MS-Word HTML some users paste into CMS.

Comment: I also didn't specify that I'm using Google App Engine, where I can only introduce pure-Python libraries.